# Can the Google Search Appliance crawl AJAX pages?

Tags: crawlable-ajax

I have page which loads content using AngularJS via AJAX calls but we also use the Google Search Appliance (GSA) for search in the website.

Is it possible to crawl the content loaded using AJAX in GSA?